# How to vertically center h1 and span in a li

Tags: css, center, vertical-alignment

I have been trying to find a solution for this but still not able to do it.

I need to vertically center the h1 and span within the `description_content` li.

However, there is a catch. The  only appears if the Phone variable is not empty. So I need to do it in a way that Seller and Phone: are vertically centered together and in the same time, if no Phone, only the Seller is centered by itself:

```
<li id="description_content">
     <h1>Seller</h1>
     <br>  <br>
     <span>Phone: </span> <br>
</li>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#description_content{
    height:163px !important;
    font-size:16px;
    }

#description_content h1{
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding:14px 10px 20px 7px;
    }

#description_content span{
    padding:0 10px 0 7px;
    float:left;
    font-weight:normal !important;
    }
```

I tried several different possibilities, including the code below, it centers the content but also messes the `li` that follow after:

```
display:table-cell!important;
vertical-align:middle!important;
```

Here is a fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/pazzesco/vykqv19j/

Any ideas as to how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood from the comments, you don't want all your `li` on the same line.

Use the following structure:

```
<li class="description_content">
    <div class="li-wrapper">
        <h1>Seller</h1>
        <span>Phone: </span>
    </div>
</li>
```

Then, display your `li` as a table and your `li-wrapper` as a table-cell vertically aligned at the middle.

```
.description_content{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height:163px !important;
  font-size:16px;
}

.description_content .li-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```